# ¿Cómo obtener la profundidad de color en bits de una imagen?

Tags: python, imagen

En Python, ¿cómo puedo conocer la profundidad de color en bits de una imagen digital almacenada en un fichero **TIFF**? Por ejemplo: 8, 16, 32 bits, etc.

Un enfoque habitual es utilizar la biblioteca [**PIL**](http://pythonware.com/products/pil/) para cargar los datos de imagen; sin embargo, al crear un objeto de imagen de esta forma, los métodos asociados a ese objeto dependerán del tipo de imagen cargada, por lo que algunos métodos como `bits` o `_getexif` no están disponibles para imágenes TIFF. Con este enfoque también se tiene el método `mode` que arroja información relacionada con el tipo de dato almacenado por píxel; es útil, pero generalizar la extracción de la profundidad de color en bits quizá requiera de una función menos sencilla de lo que se cree, pues existen muchas combinaciones para los modos.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Sí, abrir la imagen con PIL, pero el único método que muestra información al respecto es `mode`, pero pueden haber muchos distintos modos como para extraer de ellos esa información con una función sencilla.

Comment: Y usaste Pillow?

Comment: Sí, ya usé Pillow, no hay métodos adicionales para imágenes TIFF.

Answer (score 4):

Si **solo** necesitas saber la profundidad en bits de la imagen, puedes leer e interpretar la cabecera del fichero `TIFF` con `Python` puro para poder obtener el dato. Necesitas el módulo [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html) (está en la librería estándar) como única dependencia.

El siguiente código es un ejemplo que creo que funciona, lo he probado con cuatro tipos de `tiff` distintos,

1. monocromático (1 bit/pixel)
2. escala de grises (normalmeente 4 u 8 bits/pixel)
3. paleta de colores (normalmente 8 bits/pixel)
4. RGB (24 bits, 3 bytes/pixel)

.

```
import struct

def get_tiff_depth(filename):
    bits_per_sample=1
    samples_per_pixel=1
    photometric_interpretation = None
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        byte_order = f.read(2)
        if byte_order == 'II':
            prefix = '<'
        elif byte_order == 'MM':
            prefix = '>'
        else:
            raise ValueError('El fichero no parece ser un TIFF')
        (magic_number, offset) = struct.unpack(prefix + 'hI', f.read(6))
        if magic_number != 42:
            raise ValueError('El fichero no parece ser un TIFF')
        f.seek(offset)
        num_entries, = struct.unpack(prefix+'h', f.read(2))
        for i in range(num_entries):
            tag = f.read(12)
            (id_tag, type_tag, num_values, value) = struct.unpack(prefix+'hhii', tag)
            if id_tag == 258:
                bits_per_sample = value
            if id_tag == 262:
                photometric_interpretation = value
            elif id_tag == 277:
                samples_per_pixel = value
    if photometric_interpretation == 2: # rgb:
        return 24
    else:
        return bits_per_sample * samples_per_pix
```

Nota: Puedes obtener más información de la estructura interna de los ficheros TIFF [aqui](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf), pero es aburrido con ganas.

Comment: Con esta función evalué una imagen que necesito utilizar y perfectamente devolvió el dato correcto; sin embargo, intenté abrir otra imagen TIFF de características similares y el resultado es un número completamente erróneo. No adjunto las imágenes porque pesan más de 100 MB.

Answer (score 2):

Alguna vez he usado ImageMagick para alguna cosa y consultas por ejemplo `identify -verbose name.png` y aunque no se mucho de Python creo que PythonMagick esta relacionado con esta asi que creo que usted podria usarlo de esta manera:

```
import PythonMagick
image = PythonMagick.Image("YouFileName")
print image.depth()
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando la librería de imágenes de Python, [**PIL**](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) hay un método llamado `bits` que te da esa información, aunque yo nunca la he usado con imágenes TIFF.

```
import Image
imagen = Image.open("foto.jpg")
im.bits
```

Comment: no he podido encontrar en la documentación este metodo, pero hay un attributo llamado [mode](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm#mode) que puede servir para   determinar la profundidad de la imagen.

Comment: es posible que el codigo tenga un error en im.bits? saludos

Comment: Este método no funciona con imágenes TIFF. Por cierto, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre importar `Image` como `import Image` y `from PIL import Image`?

Comment: Recomiendo utilizar Pillow en vez de PIL. PIL tiene un buen tiempo sin darle mantenimiento, mientras que Pillow es un fork amistoso de PIL, con una documentación más clara y con más soporte para diversas versiones de Python. http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/

Comment: @OSjerick realmente si escribes `import Image` te dará un error, ya que es parte del módulo de PIL(Low), así que lo correcto debe ser `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: @Jeasoft pues no me da error. ;)

Comment: @OSjerick ok, que raro. Digo, si usas PIL por lo general deberás importarlo así, quizás estamos hablando de alguna librería diferente. Estás usando PIL(Low)? A mi me da error si no lo importo como te indiqué.

Comment: @Jeasoft Estoy usando Anaconda en Windows, revisando los paquetes instalados `conda list` no muestra a Pillow sino PIL 1.1.7. No uso mucho la PC de casa, pero en la PC del trabajo (que uso para todo), con OpenSUSE, `conda list` lista Pillow en lugar de PIL. Entiendo que ambos paquetes se importan con el mismo nombre, ¿cierto?

Comment: Ah, debe ser por eso. @OSjerick. Y si, debe ser así, aunque Anaconda trae algunas configuraciones algo diferentes a como si usaras Python por defecto. Mira este pedazo, quizás te pueda servir.  http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/handbook/concepts.html?highlight=depth#modes

Comment: Aquí se puede ver en qué sistemas operativos está disponible Pillow a través de Anaconda: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pillow

Comment: Y concuerdo con @Jeasoft, olviden PIL para siempre y usen Pillow, PIL solo funciona en Python Legacy (Python 2)